# How to find all conditional both false and true in nested conditional by using PHP and return it to array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm create a function to insert and update with many conditional and I want to find out all that conditional both false and true and return it as array to client for checking if some data is missing or can't update or insert.

I've used  **$return** to find out which one conditional is work or not.

```
  public function trans_issue_till() {

        if (Request::ajax()) {

            $return = [];
            $rule = [
                'till_account_id' => 'required',
                'from_account' => 'required', 
            ];
            $fromacc = Request::input('from_account');
            if ($this->CheckPermId_from_session(90) == true) {
                $fromacc = Request::input('coa_name');
            }
            $data = [
                'till_account_id' => Request::input('till_account_id'),
                'from_account' => $fromacc, 
            ];
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rule);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                $return['form'] = false;
            } else {

                $update = Teller::where('id', '=', $data['till_account_id'])->update(array('balance' => $data['balance']));
                $insert = DB::table('till_transaction')->insert($data);
                if(!$update) {
                    $return['upd_bl'] = false;
                } if(!$insert){
                    $return['ins_trans'] = false;
                }else{
                    $return;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $return['ins_trans'] = 'login';
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        foreach($return as $items){
            var_dump($items);
        }
       return $...........
    }
```

as the final sentence I used **foreach**  for check all the array index which one is true and false after that return to browser.

Comment: do you want to return just true or false  ?? You can just return array

Comment: I want to filter all the true or false from some if conditional and return it for view in laravel